# Eliminar una columna de sqlite en c#

Tags: c#, sqlite

¿Cual es el comando para eliminar una columna en sqlite? Ya tengo el codigo para eliminar la comuna de la tabla que deseo, pero no encuentro el comando que debo usar par el SQLiteCommand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si analizamos la documentacion

[SQLite ALTER TABLE](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-alter-table/)

veras que comenta

> SQLite does not support ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN statement

Pero se podria realizar algunos paso para poder realizar la operacion

[Sqlite Drop Column](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Sqlite_Drop_Column)

que se resumen en

- crear una nueva tabla sin el campo que quieres eliminar,
- volcar los datos a esta,
- eliminar la tabla original
- renombrar la nueva tabla

alli lo explica con algo de codigo para ver que comando utilizar

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t1_backup(a,b);
INSERT INTO t1_backup SELECT a,b FROM t1;
DROP TABLE t1;
CREATE TABLE t1(a,b);
INSERT INTO t1 SELECT a,b FROM t1_backup;
DROP TABLE t1_backup;
COMMIT;
```